# How do i get an XML attribute to display in a listbox c#

Tags: c#, xml

This is my code i got all the data from xml file to a list box the only one missing is the attribute i am having some difficulty trying to get the attribute to show up. not sure what exactly to do or what i am missing. i've never done xml before.

```
string startPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\ContactManager.xml";
        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(startPath);
        string Names = "";
        string sex = "";

        while (textReader.Read())
        {
            switch (textReader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                    sex = textReader.GetAttribute("Sex");
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    Names = textReader.Name;
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    lbDisplay.Items.Add(sex + Names + ": " + textReader.Value);
                    break; 
            }

        }
```

these are some of the elements in the xml file `Sex` is the attribute.

```
<Contact Sex="M">
<FirstName>Mickey</FirstName>
<LastName>Mouse</LastName>
<PhoneNumber>401-555-1212</PhoneNumber>
<FaxNumber>401-666-6666</FaxNumber>
<EmailAddress>mmouse@disney.com</EmailAddress>
</Contact>
```

Comment: Looks like a simple name mismatch. Your attribute name is "Sex", not "Contact".

Comment: @JacobProffitt i tried that still doesn't show up in list box

Comment: Is there a </Contact> tag?  Otherwise that XML is invalid.  It looks like maybe Contact is the parent node for the other values

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yes their is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code to:

```
    string startPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\ContactManager.xml";
    XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(startPath);
    string Names = "";
    string sex = "";

    while (textReader.Read())
    {
        switch (textReader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                Names = textReader.Name;
              if(textReader.Name == "Contact") sex = textReader.GetAttribute("Sex");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                Console.WriteLine();
                lbDisplay.Items.Add(sex + Names + ": " + textReader.Value);
                break; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Angel is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Angel can you explain to me what you want to show in the listbox? the sex only or the first name , last name and sex?

Comment: I already got the first, last name, etc. on the list box the only thing i need is `Sex`. i have multiple contacts, so for each i contact i want the sex to be displayed before each contact.

Comment: @Angel I edit the code now you get the sex with the other information

Comment: thanks alot that solved my problem ill mess around with it so it doesn't display in front of every tag :))